# TypeScript function using Omit for an argument loses type information for the argument

Tags: typescript

I have a function getResults that accepts a Type. I need another function (eg getResults2) which takes `Foo` as an argument but without the property `value`.

https://codesandbox.io/s/black-night-5vr4h8?file=/src/App.tsx:294-305

```
type Foo = { value: string } | { oldValue: string } | { newValue: string };

function getResults(input: Foo):string {
  if('value' in input) {
    return input.value;
  }
  if('oldValue' in input) {
    return input.oldValue;
  }
  return input.newValue;
}

function getResults2(input: Omit<Foo, 'value'>):string {
  if('oldValue' in input) {
    return input.oldValue;
  }
  return input.newValue;
}
```

Im getting TypeScript errors for both return lines in `getResults2`

> (property) oldValue: unknown
> Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)

> any
> Property 'newValue' does not exist on type 'Omit<Foo, "value">'.ts(2339)

Comment: You don't want `Omit`, you want `Exclude` to exclude `{ value: string }` from the union https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludeuniontype-excludedmembers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want `Omit`, you want `Exclude` to exclude `{ value: string }` [from the union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludeuniontype-excludedmembers)

```
type Foo = { value: string } | { oldValue: string } | { newValue: string };

function getResults(input: Foo):string {
  if('value' in input) {
    return input.value;
  }
  if('oldValue' in input) {
    return input.oldValue;
  }
  return input.newValue;
}

function getResults2(input: Exclude<Foo, { value: string }>):string {
  if('oldValue' in input) {
    return input.oldValue;
  }
  return input.newValue;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=18&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvKA3AhgGwK4QBcUAzsAE4CWAdgOZQC+UAPmlHDgCYBquBxZKnUYs21CAHde+IqQo16DANwAoFQDM81AMbBKcalFoRgAJQgk8OYCQAUNMHmDF4cAJSFBCtCqhRK6rYA5NgyQf6GDk5uPn5+5CZ45JHUjsAAdKEEqn4Mvv6BQRw8fBDhNBFpMaj58YnJlU7pxdLZ+Xl1wEkpaeniUqWqeRpauvqGxmYWVjYATPapTsQAogAe2vicEAA8rgA0bFmyXsIMAHweJ-Q1fgHBLaXlPdGxcQldDVEZDzI5jPnvbqNDL9VoQIZAA)

Comment: This works but isnt ideal as the shape of { value: string } may change. Eg if in future it became { value: string; foo: string } then I would have to update the Exclude type in many places. Is there a solution with better DX?

Comment: @Evanss I mean I wouldn't do it this way *at all* but I gave you what you asked for, maybe I should have pushed back more instead, my bad. I would refactor the types so that there's Foo (`A | B`) and Foo+ (`A | B | C`) and getResults takes a Foo+ and getResults2 just takes a Foo. Don't get me wrong I'm glad utility types exist and I occasionally even write some of my own but generally speaking when I find myself reaching for one it's because I (or some third party) designed something poorly in the first place. Refactor time.